# How to securely provide ssl keystore and key passwords

Tags: apache-kafka, jetty, keystore, jks

I use ssl keystores for Jetty 9 and Kafka. I need to provide keystore and key passwords to access the keystore and private key. However, I don't want to provide these passwords in clear text in the configuration files. What other options are there to securely provide/encrypt the passwords? what is the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 1):

Since Kafka 2.0.0, all password configs can be preloaded in zookeeper before you start brokers. The `kafka-configs.sh` tool can be used to store passwords in an encrypted format in Zookeeper avoiding the need to specify them in plaintext in the properties file.

See the [Updating Broker Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#dynamicbrokerconfigs) section in the Kafka docs, especially the "Updating Password Configs in ZooKeeper Before Starting Brokers" paragraph.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Could you may be direct me to an example of how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation I linked in my answer? If so what is not clear?

Comment: How to I know the `listener.name.{listenerName}` or how do I set it?

Comment: It's the name of the listeners you have set in `listeners`. For example, if you have `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092` then `PLAINTEXT` is a listener name

Comment: Thanks. I ran the config command, however I am getting an error `ERROR Dynamic password config listener.name.SSL.ssl.truststore.password could not be decoded, ignoring. (kafka.server.DynamicBrokerConfig)
Aug 13 11:31:50 available-kafka-03 kafka[31050]: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Password encoder secret not configured` even though I have specified `password.encoder.secret` in the command. Any thougths on this?

Comment: This is the command `bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zk1:2181,zk2:2181,zk3:2181 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --alter --add-config 'listener.name.ssl.ssl.key.password=123456,listener.name.ssl.ssl.truststore.location=/home/deploy/keystore/server.truststore.jks,listener.name.ssl.ssl.truststore.password=123456,listener.name.ssl.ssl.keystore.location=/home/deploy/keystore/kafka1.server.keystore.jks,listener.name.ssl.ssl.keystore.password=123456,password.encoder.secret=NeBL4Gs8B3ex5K7p'`. Is it mandatory to specify `password.encoder.secret`  in `server.properties`?

Comment: @MickaelMaison Can you please help me with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900529/kafka-update-jaas-config-dynamically

Comment: Although this question is a bit old, but I found out that putting the `password.encoder.secret` in the beginning of all props works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is mandatory to add password encoder in `server.properties`,
otherwise server can not decode password.

It works for me when I add `password.encoder.secret` to `server.properties`.