# Kafka : Update jaas config dynamically

Tags: configuration, apache-kafka, jaas, broker

I have setup the jaas config for kafka using `sasl.jaas.config` property. I want to update this config and add users dynamically.

As per this doc - http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#dynamicbrokerconfigs, we can do that by using `bin/kafka-configs.sh`.

The above doc has config column, which says as follow - [image]

I have tried updating `sasl.jaas.config` with below command:

`bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 59 --alter --add-config sasl.jaas.config="KafkaServer {\n  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required\n  username=\"myuser\"\n  password=\"mypassword\";\n};\nClient {\n  org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required\n  username=\"myuser2\"\n  password=\"mypassword2\";\n};"`

But it gives me following error:

`requirement failed: Invalid entity config: all configs to be added must be in the format "key=val"`

If I look to above column, it says the format for value of `sasl.jaas.config` property is `(=)*`. What does this means?

How the value for 'sasl.jaas.config' should be passed to update jaas config dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's possible to dynamically update `sasl.jaas.config` to add more users, the default Plain login module is not intended to be used in production.

Instead you should define callback handlers to handle authentication of users. This is described in the [Kafka Sasl Plain docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_production).

Another option that requires more work (but give even more flexibility) is to create your own login module. The process is described in [Can Kafka be provided with custom LoginModule to support LDAP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295512/can-kafka-be-provided-with-custom-loginmodule-to-support-ldap/47295711#47295711)

---

Regarding the error message you get, this seems to be an issue with the `kafka-config.sh` tool. It's not expecting the config value to contain `=`. You should be able to update that config using the AdminClient API.

I couldn't find an existing issue in JIRA so created a new one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8010

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs, How can I use AdminClient API to update sasl.jaas.config, never used that, any example on that would be helpful, Thanks again.

Comment: I did checked on http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_production, but it contains limited info on that. Do you have any example/link which will guide more on "Writing callback handlers to handle authentication of users".

Comment: See KIP-86 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-86%3A+Configurable+SASL+callback+handlers#KIP-86:ConfigurableSASLcallbackhandlers-sample_plain) for callback handler examples

Comment: To use the AdminClient, have a look at the Javadocs for `alterConfigs()` http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#alterConfigs-java.util.Map-
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54024829/java-kafka-adminclient-topic-configuration-configuration-values-are-overwritten/54026448#54026448 for an example

Comment: OK Thanks, will check on both.